# Need to obfuscate/wrap txt files in Tcl based project flow

Tags: tcl, wrapper, obfuscation

I have TCL based project in Linux env, where TCL scripts are used to create the project, run and perform error analysis. Once the run is complete, a set of algorithms (in txt format) are fed back to the flow for error correction.

To hide the txt files, I need to obfuscate/wrap them for delivery to the customer so as not to reveal the algorithms in the files. Please could someone suggest any utility/tool that can obfuscate/wrap and interface the txt files to the project flow so that TCL can read the files automatically without user intervention?

Comment: How much do you want to package up together? How resistant to inspection do you want to make it? For some users, just changing the file extension is enough to make the file opaque!

Comment: There's also zipkits and various forms of compiler/obfuscator. The right approach depends on the sophistication of the users; it's possible to build things that are more resistant to analysis and modification than even normal native binaries… _but it isn't easy._

Answer (score 1):

One of many ways is using tools to make a stand-alone executable, for example freewrap utility:

http://freewrap.sourceforge.net/

It's regularly updated and really modern and easy to use in Linux and Windows.